# Angular Cypress component test error: Cannot access '<Component>' before initialization

Tags: angular, cypress, angular-module, cypress-component-test-runner, e2e

I am trying to run spec for my Angular component using Cypress. But I've got the following error in Cypress logs:

```
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.


  > Cannot access 'TextsFilterComponent' before initialization


When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.


We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.
View stack trace
 Print to console
    at Module.TextsFilterComponent (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/spec-1.js:80491:69)
    at 36283 (webpack://angular/./src/app/shared/components/games/texts-filter/texts-filter.module.ts:12:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/runtime.js:23:42)
    at 70275 (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/spec-1.js:80476:78)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/runtime.js:23:42)
    at 44549 (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/spec-1.js:80241:78)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/runtime.js:23:42)
    at 37511 (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/spec-1.js:79929:69)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/runtime.js:23:42)
    at 67953 (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/spec-1.js:27564:82)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/runtime.js:23:42)
    at 70111 (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/spec-1.js:26774:74)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/runtime.js:23:42)
    at 12063 (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/src/spec-1.js:17404:67)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:808
```

My spec looks like this:

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { FormFieldModule } from '../form-field/form-field.module';
import { TextsFilterComponent } from './texts-filter.component';
import { TextsFilterModule } from './texts-filter.module';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import {
  ChangeDetectorRef, EventEmitter,
} from '@angular/core';
import { TextsService, SyllablesService, WordsService } from '../../../../core/services/games';
import { AuthService } from '../../../../core/services';

it('mounts', () => {
  cy.mount(TextsFilterComponent, {
    imports: [
      TextsFilterModule,
      CommonModule,
      FormFieldModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      NgSelectModule,
      TranslateModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatSelectModule,
    ],
    providers: [
      TextsService,
      ChangeDetectorRef,
      AuthService,
      WordsService,
      SyllablesService,
    ],
    componentProperties: {
      parametersForm: new FormGroup({
        test: new FormControl('x'),
      }),
      hasError: new EventEmitter(),
      customMinItems: 1,
    },
  });
});
```

My spec is in the same folder with component, so all imports are correct.

I've placed all services injected to my component in the `providers`. And all imports from module to `imports`. Also I passed some values for 2 inputs and 1 output of the component in the `componentProperties` section.

Componennt's module:

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { FormFieldModule } from '../form-field/form-field.module';
import { TextsFilterComponent } from './texts-filter.component';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [TextsFilterComponent],
  exports: [TextsFilterComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormFieldModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    TranslateModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
  ],
})
export class TextsFilterModule {}
```

And my component:

```js
// ...

@Component({
  selector: 'texts-filter',
  templateUrl: './texts-filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./texts-filter.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class TextsFilterComponent
  extends AbstractFiltersMixin(BaseFilters)
  implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, OnChanges {

  constructor(
    private _textsService: TextsService,
    private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private _authService: AuthService,
    private _wordsService: WordsService,
    private _syllablesService: SyllablesService,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  // ...
}
```

And my `cypress/support/component.ts`:

```js
import { mount } from 'cypress/angular'


declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      mount: typeof mount
    }
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('mount', mount)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was in `index.ts` file. I've used them to export all services from the folder to simplify imports:

##### index.ts

```js
export * from './api.service';
export * from './audio.service';
export * from './auth.service';
```

But this approach leads to circullar dependencies.

The best solution is to get ride of `index.ts` and import each service from it's file.

But in my case I have already had thousands of imports and I didn't want to fix all of them. So, I found another solution that helped my Jasmine and Cypress tests run.

I've added `"emitDecoratorMetadata": false` property to `tsconfig.json` and error disappeared!

##### tsconfig.json

```json
{
   ...,
   "compilerOptions": {
      ...
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a circular reference between `TextsFilterComponent` and `TextsFilterModule`.

There's only the one export from the module, the component itself, so you probably don't need it in `cy.mount()`.

All the other imports the module brings in are covered in your mount `imports` already.

```js
it('mounts', () => {
  cy.mount(TextsFilterComponent, {
    imports: [
      // TextsFilterModule,           // avoid circular mounting error 
      CommonModule,
      FormFieldModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      NgSelectModule,
      TranslateModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatSelectModule,
    ],
```

Comment: I tried this, but, unfortunately, got the same error

Comment: There must be another circular reference - what does your `cy.mount()` look like (if you have a custom mount).

Comment: I updated my question and included it

Comment: Thanks, that's clearly not the source of the problem.

Comment: I see `extends AbstractFiltersMixin` - is that the base of any other imported service or module - I see `FormFieldModule` and `TextsFilterComponent` are local to the project.

Comment: It's a while since I used Angular  but I recall that circular references were difficult to unwind. Sorry I'm out of suggestions, if you have a repo I will take a further look at it.

Comment: I don't think that any modules like `FormFieldModule` does circular import. But I've just noticed something strange: even when I removed `TextsFilterModule` import there's been a line `at 36283 (webpack://angular/./src/app/shared/components/games/texts-filter/texts-filter.module.ts:12:17)` in Cypress traceback. I think it still tries to use the `TextsFilterModule`. May be the problem connected with this?

Comment: It looks like a lead - does removing the import at the top of the spec help? (Sorry that also should have been in the answer).

Comment: Thank you very much for a hint about circular imports. I have just found that declarations in `index.ts` files lead to many circular imports, so I removed them. I edited your answer and approved it